# GNUPG Escaping echoed data in shell_exec

Tags: php, shell, exec, shell-exec, gnupg

I really want to go about this securely, as there is customer data involved.

I am using GNUPG via the command line because I am on shared hosting, and the PHP class is not available. So my code is as follows:

```
putenv("GNUPGHOME=/home/me/.gnupg");

$gpg = '/usr/bin/gpg';
$gpgrecipient = 'email';
$mailrecp = 'email';
$plain = 'Here is the encrypted Text Here is the encrypted Text Here is the
    encrypted Text Here is the encrypted Text Here is the encrypted Text Here is the
    encrypted Text Here is the encrypted Text Here is the encrypted Text Here is the  
    encrypted Text';



$encrypted = shell_exec("echo {$plain} | {$gpg} --no-auto-check-trustdb --lock-never -e -a -r {$gpgrecipient} ");
```

So, how do I go about escaping `$plain`, while preserving data integrity?

If I just use `escapeshellcmd()` it tends to mess up formatting.

I am a bit leery of saving anything out to a file because it is sensitive data on shared hosting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know php very well, but have you considered using `proc_open` rather than `shell_exec`?  It seems cleaner than invoking a shell command to echo the input and pipe it to `gpg`.

But if you'd rather use `proc_open`, consider using `printf` rather than `echo -n`; it has better defined behavior.  For example (untested):

```
$encrypted = shell_exec("printf '%s' '{$plain}' | {$gpg} ...`
```

With `echo`, you run the risk that the `echo` command (which could be either a shell built-in or the `/bin/echo` command) might interpret some of its arguments as something other than strings to be printed.

Comment: I haven't used proc_open - seems a lot more complicated in the way of piping, but hopefully I can figure it out.  Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `escapeshellarg`? And `echo` adds a newline to the end of the string on the output, so you might want to use `-n`: [Demo](http://codepad.org/KZqqPuUL)

```
<?php

$gpg = '/usr/bin/gpg';
$gpgrecipient = 'email';
$mailrecp = 'email';
$plain = 'Here is the encrypted Text Here is the encrypted Text Here is the
    encrypted Text Here is the encrypted Text Here is the encrypted Text Here is the
    encrypted Text Here is the encrypted Text Here is the encrypted Text Here is the  
    encrypted Text';


$plain = escapeshellarg($plain);

$cmd = "echo -n {$plain} | {$gpg} --no-auto-check-trustdb --lock-never -e -a -r {$gpgrecipient} ";

echo $cmd;
```